# Change Alt-Key shortcut in MS Office for custom addin in VSTO

Tags: ms-office, vsto, office-addins, ms-project, excel-addins

I'm developing an addin for MS Project via VSTO and I am wondering if there are any way to change the letter that appear under the tab of my addin when user presses Alt key?

Suppose I was developing Team addin and I want a user to press `T` instead of `Y2` to get to my addin.
[image]

I understand that it brings to the table potential conflicts because this way my shortcut could potentially conflict with other custom ones. But I guess it should be quite easy to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to specify the `keytip`. It has to not conflict with another visible tab, or another control on the same tab. It can be 1-3 letters long.

This does not work for tabs you did not create.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I don't have Ribbon XML, but I have Ribbon.cs, opened it in designer and specified desired shortcut in KeyTip, rebuilt, launched and it doesn't work. Tried to specify several different values for it to be sure about uniqueness. Also tried to set it in Ribbon partial class. As a test tried to change a label on tab and it changes fine. Do you know if I need to reinstall the addin before I see the change or what the issue could be?

Comment: the weird part in it is that KeyTip for some reason doesn't set the shortcut on tab, but it sets it on other buttons inside the ribbon

Comment: I'm using Word 2010, so maybe they changed it in 2013 so that you can't change it for tabs, but only for controls? Or maybe Excel is different but I doubt that. In fact I doubt both possibilities.

Comment: You definitely have to reinstall/update the addin to see the change, but if you're running it from Visual Studio that should happen automatically.

Comment: Ah. This is a tab you didn't create, isn't it? I don't think you can change this for tabs you didn't create.

Comment: I'm trying to set the shortcut to the my addin tab, I don't have access to KeyTip property of other tabs. I'm using VS15 and it should update because it updates for the shortcuts inside ribbon and I can change the name of my tab. So weird.

Comment: Do you mean the 'TabAddins' tab? That one is built-in, but added by default in new projects. A custom tab would have a ControlIdType (expand ControlId) of Custom. A built-in tab has a ControlIdType of Office.

Comment: I've created my own tab and trying to change KeyTip on it. When I open its properties - I see that it has ControlIdType=Custom. But KeyTip property (it is set to 'PS' now) doesn't work even it doesn't conflict with anything else (tried a couple of different values to be sure)